# Using JPA Criteria API, how can I execute this type of Delete Query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
DELETE FROM table_name
  WHERE NOT IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM table_name
    WHERE user_id = 1
    ORDER BY date DESC
    LIMIT 50
  )
```

I've tried creating a subquery, but it doesn't seem to allow you to set an ORDER BY or LIMIT value.

Comment: You are correct that JPQL (and hence Criteria) will not allow `LIMIT` (since that is provided by `setFirstResult`/ `setMaxResults` for the outer query, but NEVER on a subquery), and `ORDER BY` is not available in a subquery. You are then down to either specific JPA providers maybe allowing it in JPQL (DataNucleus does allow a form of "limit" in JPQL, as well as ORDER ... I'd expect Hibernate to offer one of those), or using SQL. Criteria is a fixed API so you won't get JPA providers allowing those